# How to target specific Calabash feature files?

Tags: android, cucumber, automated-tests, calabash

I've been looking for this answer for quite a while and I'm not able to figure it out just yet.

Say I have a test environment and a production one. I created calabash scenarios which need to be different whether I'm running on test or prod. All my scenarios have been written in **/feature/xxx.feature**

Problem being, when I run the tests, all the ***.feature** will be run. Therefore I created an environment variable which I change according to which environment I wanna run the test onto.

How can I target the right .feature files? How to tell Calabash: *when the environment variable is set to "production" please only run the **/feature/prodution/***.feature files?*

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I recommend you to try this library: https://github.com/mauriciotogneri/green-coffee

It's based on Espresso, so tests run faster than using Calabash.You can run individual .feature tests or a group of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really a cucumber question.

I recommend using tags.  The examples below are for iOS, but the principles apply to Android.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Tags

You can see how we use tags in the[Calabash iOS Smoke Test App.](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/tree/master/CalSmokeApp/features)

```
# Run the animation tests
$ bundle exec cucumber -t @animations

# Run the backdoor tests
$ bundle exec cucumber -t @backdoor
```

You can combine tags with cucumber profiles for more advanced behaviors.

```
 # Run the backdoor tests in the production environment
 $ bundle exec -p production -t @backdoor
```

- [Cucumber profiles](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml)
- [Cucumber profiles for iOS Simulators and Devices](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/config/cucumber.yml)
- [Cucumber profiles for the Xamarin Test Cloud](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/config/xtc-profiles.yml)

Answer (score 1):

you can target a specific feature using this command.

`bundler exec calabash-android run <apk>.apk <feature folder>/<feature name to execute>.feature`

For example:

`bundler exec calabash-android run <apk>.apk feature/Home.feature`

Also you can use the tags with the feature

`bundler exec calabash-android run <apk>.apk <feature folder>/<feature to execure>.feature --tags @<tag name>`

For example:

`bundler exec calabash-android run <apk>.apk feature/Home.feature --tags @test`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have homepage.feature and want to run entire feature file

run entire feature file: calabash-android run apkname.apk features/homepage.feature

run particular test : calabash-android run apkname.apk features/homepage.feature --tags @smoke